# What is the threshold used by the Windows memory manager to determine when to begin swapping pages to disk?

Tags: windows, memory, virtual, threshold

I see this comment in the Perfmon counter "Memory"-"Working Set" description:

> If free memory in the computer is above a threshold, pages are left in
>   the Working Set of a process even if they are not in use.  When free
>   memory falls below a threshold, pages are trimmed from Working Sets.

I haven't been able to find any documentation regarding this threshold value. It is a percentage of available RAM? Is it when the Commit Charge consumes all available RAM? How does the system treat Kernel pages, vs User mode pages?

So my questions are:

- What is that threshold?
- Is there a way to detect it?
- Do different versions of windows have different behavior or thresholds?

The scenario is that my process will try to use as much memory as there is available physical RAM. Once that limit is reached I can deallocate and cache on disk certain chunks of memory to make room for new stuff. It does this to help alleviate page file thrashing when memory conditions are low. I'd like to perform the deallocation BEFORE the memory manager begins swapping pages to disk because the memory usage has passed the magic threshold.

I currently use the MEMORYSTATUSEX::ullAvailPhys value (filled by GlobalMemoryStatusEx) to identify the amount of available physical memory.

Comment: You probably shouldn't try to do that: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/01/18/10257834.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info Harry. In this case, we have significant control over the machine that will be running this app and I can make accurate assumptions about the application being given nearly exclusive access to memory. So, I'm not worried about playing nice with other apps. :)

Comment: Have you considered turning virtual memory off entirely?

Answer (score 2):

Windows uses as much RAM as possible either for programs and for disk-cache so it doesn't swap tremendously at some point...

if you want more RAM for running application you have to diminish the disk-cache.

There is a tool to set the disk-cache by SysInternal.

```
cacheset.exe
```

You can find it here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897561.aspx